# How to make chromebook keyboard work under gnome wayland?

Tags: gnome, keyboard, wayland

I'm looking for help to make my chromebook keyboard work under gnome wayland (ubuntu 17.10).

I use this script under X11 that work perfectly 
https://pastebin.com/Ym7nM1Ec

Do you know how I can adapt it for wayland ? 
Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Well after some research it seem that the script doesn't need any modification. The problem is that Gnome Shell doesn't allow to change the keyboard model. On X11 it's not a problem since we use some X11 tools to do so but they doesn't work with wayland. I hope the feature will be add to Gnome.

https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=777000